# gwt multiple field suggest box

Tags: java, gwt

is it is possible to make multiple suggest values in suggestbox GWT

```
example..
if i search for a

Abraham   25   1984
Abi       23   1987
Aram      26   1999
```

this should be in suggest box is it is possible ....

```
like this icefaces (check second textbox)
http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsing the GWT Javadoc anwser your question : http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html

You could also read those articles which are intersting :

- http://development.lombardi.com/?p=39
- http://development.lombardi.com/?p=44
- http://development.lombardi.com/?p=45

Answer (score 1):

There's also a library that permits to do that natively:  http://code.google.com/p/advanced-suggest-select-box/

It also permits to have icons and handles other aspects (like a strict mode to work like a select box still proposing suggestions on typing, have other filtering algorithm, etc...